# Selective django/jquery form submission

Tags: jquery, html, django, forms

I have a search field at the top of my django template (with no surrounding form tags):

```
<input name="q" id="id_q" /> 
<input type="submit" id="id_s" value="Search">
```

As of now, the search key is submitted with a button press or by clicking enter:

```
$(function($) {
    $(":submit").click(function() {
        window.location = "{% url search %}?q=" + $("#id_q").val();
    });
});
```

Now, I'm adding in [django-registration](http://code.google.com/p/django-registration/).  As a result, I have a login template that resembles the following:

```
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="form_errors">
            {% for err in form.non_field_errors %}
                <div class="form_error_message">{{ err }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>  
    {% endif %}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="block">
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
            {% for err in field.errors %}
                <span class="error_message">{{ err }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <div style="padding-left:11em; padding-bottom:1em;">
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

It took me a while to figure out why attempting to log in sent me to a search page.  I realized that clicking Enter after entering the password was activating the search key, not the username/password submission.

How can I configure the template such that I can type in a search query, hit enter, and activate the search view OR enter my account information, hit enter, and log in?  Basically, how can I specify that an enter key press "belongs" to its requisite function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url search %}">
    <input name="q" id="id_q" /> 
    <input type="submit" id="id_s" value="Search">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function($) {
    $(":submit").click(function() {
        window.location = "{% url search %}?q=" + $("#id_q").val();
    });
});
</script>
```

That's the way to do it:

```
<form method="get" action="{% url search %}">
    <input name="q" id="id_q" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" /> 
    <input type="submit" id="id_s" value="Search">
</form>
```

Note that the javascript is gone, and that the form now relies on using the "get" method. So, the javascript won't conflict anymore.

Also I added a value to the q input, as a free goodie B)

Jeff Sickel:

> Deleted code is debugged code.

If you really wanted to fix the js, you could do as such:

```
$("form[action={% url search %}]").submit(// ...
```

Or add an id to your search form:

```
$("#search_form").submit(// ...
```

Comment: This is helpful but still isn't quite getting to what I need.  Yes, the search box will submit when the enter key is pressed, but pressing the enter key after filling in the login form information triggers the search function.  Is there a way to trigger the login after entering the password while still allowing the enter key to work if the user instead uses the search box?

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding what I need to do.  I'm doing two things.  First, I'm removing the javascript code.  Second, I'm altering the search box code by adding <form> around it with the method "get".  This replicates the code you have above.  This was helpful, because using the search box (that you wrote out above) submits when the enter key is pressed. But trying to log in (using the form I wrote out at the end of my question) does not submit when the enter key is pressed.  I tried changing that form's post to get, but then it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Does it submit when you click the submit button ? Are you sure that action="." is appropriate ?

Comment: It does submit when I click the button. So I assume the action="." is appropriate?  But when I hit enter, it acts like I'm hitting the search button.

Comment: Can you extract the HTML so that we can reproduce the error ? If you're in the login form, press enter, and that it submits another form, is because there is another mistake in the HTML.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I found an additional bit of code that was capturing the enter-key press.  I didn't realize it was there.  Thanks